# Laravel 5.5 Google OAuth authentication using Socialite Package (Legacy People API has not been used in project)

Tags: api, authentication, google-api, laravel-socialite

Im trying to add google authentication for my application which built with laravel 5.5 with [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite). So for that I have created a google developer account via [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis) and enabled **google+ api**.

[image: console]

[image: api enabled]

[image: console 2]

So when I try to register when it redirect to call back url it gives me below error. I have gone through lot of documentations and stackoverflow questions almost. But no luck.

This is the error

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (403)

```
Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project
```

Could anyone please help me on this
Thanks
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

use Socialite::**with**('**G**oogle')->user();

it was help me

Comment: Im almost using socialite

Comment: can you help me on this

Comment: I use Socialite::driver('google')->user() and app throws this error, but when I change it to Socialite::with('Google')->user() it started work without any errors

Comment: still giving me the error could you please tell me is there is anything special I need to  do in google console

Comment: may be enable Google People API, Google + API, Google Contacts API.
I enabled them before this changing in code. May be this is a part of solution